# MySQL connection with VB.NET via internet!

Tags: mysql, vb.net

While connecting to mysql via VB.NET, I'm getting the following problem. What can be the solution or what am i missing???

---

### Host '113.199.138.240' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: I think he needs to know the way to connect to remote MySql server using VB.NET

Comment: Sounds like the problem's pretty obvious.  That host is blocked.  Get the admin to unblock it.  (They're OK with you connecting from there, right?)

Comment: where is that server 113.199.138.240? Is that local to VB.NET application or at the remote site?

Comment: @Umair: That's the client's external (public) IP.  Looks like a DSL from Nepal or thereabouts.

Comment: What is your connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of reasons you may not be allowed to connect:

1. Use port 3306 to connect
2. Check that your MySQL allows external connections
3. Check if local or remote firewalls prevent you from connecting.

In order to connect you need privileges:

```
grant 'privilege_type' on 'databasename'.* to '<user>'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

Comment: The error message implies that the host table was checked, meaning the connection was noticed and rejected by the server.  ("is not allowed to" connect, not "couldn't".)

Comment: You are right! I just added the grant command to the answer above.

Comment: @Umair: I have got successful connection in localhost. It's the problem when I tried to connect to web server. Ya, it's DSL from Nepal.

Comment: The connection string is :Dim strMysql As String = "Database=database_name;Data Source=64.191.56.5;User Id=myuserid;Password=mypassword"

Comment: @Costis Aivalis: I could not use the grant syntax. Can you please elaborate it??

Comment: Make sure your account uses the '%' wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_base.* TO db_user @'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd'; Just use the '%' instead of localhost. It will allow you to connect from any host.Otherwise it will only allow you to connect from localhost only. Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html. Do you have permission to grant privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Login as root the try this on mysql console:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASENAME.* TO foo@113.199.138.240 IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

You can also use wildcards **foo@'%'** means anyone can connect with **foo** username. Which is not good practice.

See also MySQL Docs on [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)